# gitpython how to add credentials to repo object

Tags: credentials, gitpython

I want to push changes to git
but I need to use specific credentials (username, pass) not ssh key.
For example I use command

```
repo = git.Repo(my_folder)
repo.remote().push(...)
$ permission denied
```

Is there a way to add these credentials to repo object?